Rate limiting concurrent web queries to multiple domains, stdlib only
Question
How to manage rate limiting concurrent web queries to multiple domains using only python stdlib?  Not asking about algorithms like leaky bucket or single-domain solutions, but how to approach data and code structures for concurrent queries to multiple domains.
Related
The following posts have useful info but don't solve my problem.  They don't address concurrent requests and per-domain rate limits, and many answers use 3rd party modules.

How to limit rate of requests to web services in Python?
What's a good rate limiting algorithm?
Which data-structure to use for "dynamic" priority queueing?
Priority queue with dynamic item priorities
Limiting concurrency and rate for Python threads
Distributed rate limiting
Distributed crawling and rate limiting / flow control

This question comes closest, quite similar setup (though I don't revisit same links).  But approach uses external database and PHP / Java, not python.  Too heavy, need a python solution.

Distributed crawling and rate limiting / flow control

Setup
Downloading data from multiple domains.  Typical pattern is:

add several download items from a first domain
add several download items from a second domain
while first domain items are downloading, hit a rate limit and backoff for awhile
continue downloading items from second domain while first domain is waiting to resume <-- HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART?

That's simplified a bit.  In reality more download items can be added at any time throughout the process, which is ongoing.
Can't / don't want to install 3rd party libs like from pypi, to minimize dependencies and maintain security.  Code should be self-contained using only python stdlib.
Current Approach
I use a producer / consumer implementation with a single queue and several worker threads for concurrent downloads.  It uses leaky bucket for rate limiting with timestamps (no discard, rate-limited items simply wait).  Works perfectly for single-domain downloads.  Conceptually like this:
def dl_worker (que) :
    while true :
        item = que.get ()
        if paused (item.domain) :   # waiting due to rate limit
            time.sleep (backofftime (item.domain))
        # dl item...

# start pool of dl threads
dlque = queue.Queue ()
workers = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool (5)
with workers :
    for x in workers._pool :
        workers.apply_async (dl_worker, dlque)

Problem: this uses a single queue for all download items.  When dl threads pause to rate limit, any items in queue for second domain are stuck waiting during pause for first domain items.
Rejected solutions

A naive fix would be for worker threads to cycle through entire queue when they hit a backoff for domain1.  Something like:

def dl_worker () :
    while true :
        item = dlque.get ()
        if paused (item.domain) :   # waiting due to rate limit
            dlque.put (item)        # move item to back of queue
            continue

        # process item...

This is wasteful.  If queue only contains items from domain1, then workers will continually shuffle items from front to back during backoff period.  Want to avoid busy-wait solutions.

Another option is to spawn separate pool of workers for each domain.  That would isolate pauses to just workers on that domain.  But domains could be quite large, resulting in huge number of threads and resource exhaustion.  And queue becomes more complicated - need a dispatcher to consume items from incoming queue and allocate to separate queues per threadpool/domain.

Could also use 3rd party libs like pyrate-limiter or ratelimit as seen here.  But that violates my stdlib only requirement, and only addresses the rate limiting issue, not the multiple domain issue.


Other Solutions
The main problem with current solution is having a single queue.  I came up with a few other approaches, but they all have drawbacks:

Use separate queue for each domain.  There doesn't seem to be a way to wait () on multiple queues in python (like select on file handles).  I have to manually poll all queues to see which are ready.  Something like (imagine suitable thread locks where needed):

allques = {}

def put (item):
    que = allques.setdefault (item.domain, queue.Queue ())
    que.put (item)

def dl_worker (que):
    while true :
        # find which queues have items ready to process
        active = [ x for x in allques if x not in paused ]
        ready  = [ a for a in active if me.allques [a].qsize () ]
        
        if ready :
            for domain in ready :
                try :
                    item = me.allques [domain].get (block = false)
                    # process item ...
                    break
                except Empty :
                    # qsize was wrong, no biggie, move on to next queue
                    pass
                            
        else :
            # wait and poll again
            time.sleep (0.5)

I dislike the sleep polling.  I could use a threading.Semaphore instead to track the number of current items across all queues (call semaphore.release on every que.put and semaphore.acquire before attempting que.get).  But that doesn't help if all queues are currently in rate-limit backoff: dl_worker will busy-wait performing the while loop, with ready being an empty list on each pass.
Using individual semaphores for each queue just creates the same polling problem.
This approach also doesn't preserve dl item order.  Just grabs first item from first ready queue it finds.  I could use random.shuffle on ready to at least randomize which queue is picked from.  Preserving item order seems difficult.  Would need a separate data structure to track insertion order across all queues.  Seems like more trouble than it's worth.

I could use two queues: active and paused.  Items are popped from active queue.  If domain is in backoff period, then stick item on paused queue until backoff expires.  I think this has the same problem though.  Namely, I need a dispatcher thread to watch paused queue and shuffle items back to active queue once their backoff period expires.

What happens when second item on paused queue expires sooner than first item?  It will be stuck waiting on the paused queue until first item is removed and put back on active queue.
Or I need a non-queue data structure for paused, so I can pull off any item that's ready.  But then I need sleep polling again (no blocking get call available).

I could use a different data structure than a queue to filter out items currently in a backoff period.  Not sure what structure this would be though. PriorityQueue doesn't seem to help.

One, its priorities are static.  My priorities are dynamic: hitting rate limit triggers a pause, and pause may increase while items are waiting (eg two workers grab items from same domain at same time. first finishes and triggers a pause, second finishes later and lengthens the pause).
Two, PriorityQueue always returns an item if available.  I can't set a backoff period to say "hold this item on the queue until time X, then return it".

I could use a heap instead of a queue to retrieve any object.  But it's hard to keep heap in sorted order.  As downloads happen and rate limits are triggered, item priority changes dynamically.  Resorting the heap every time a backoff happens seems inefficient.  And python heaps don't block on get(), they either return or throw.  Still need time.sleep polling.

Conclusion
So far option 1 seems like the best solution, despite its drawbacks.  Does anyone have better ideas?
I'm not inherently tied to a threading model.  Async might work as well.  I hate littering my code with async / await junk and the red / blue function problem.  But if there's a cleaner solution available, it's worth considering.

thanks @AhmedAEK how would that work?  interface looks the same as queue.Queue.  still have the problem where front item blocks items behind.

you seem concerned about spawning too many threads and queues, you can use asyncio with asyncio.queue. you will have only 1 thread, so you can spawn as many workers as you want to wait on as many queues as you want, coroutines are very lightweight anyway, and asyncio has many of the synchronization primitives you can think of like semaphores and events asyncio synchronization and even asyncio.sleep function.

@AhmedAEK it's a potential improvement.  however there are still issues with resource exhaustion.  not just threads / async workers, but also bandwidth.  imagine 100 domains all downloading concurrently with 5 workers each.  this is running on client machines not servers.  network responsiveness matters.

For that you should probably look up actors and their uses, it is a lot of code and there is no silver bullet.

Scheduler
Another potential solution just came to me: use a scheduler thread.  Something like this:

one input queue for all download items
scheduler thread monitors queue and immediately moves items to per-domain queues
scheduler checks whether any items are waiting on active per-domain queues (not in backoff mode)

if yes, set condition flag itemsready
if no, unset condition flag itemsready


wait until either:

another item arrives on incoming queue
shortest backoff period currently in effect expires


loop to step 2

Worker threads wait() on itemsready flag then grab next item from an active queue.  Otherwise workers sleep.
This seems like a good solution.  Not sure if scheduler needs one thread or two (one to sort incoming items, second to monitor active queues).  Because one thread can't wait on both things simultaneously: incomingqueue.get() and backofftimer.wait().  Or maybe it can, if I compute time til next backoff expiration and use that as timeout on get().
I'll work on code and post an update.
Code
This approach works beautifully.  I encapsulated all per-domain queues in a single queue class that simplifies the algorithm.  Consumers access one que object, which manages separate per-domain queues internally.  Item ready flag can be updated in get / put calls, leaving watcher thread to just monitor backoff expiration.
class Pauseque () :  # {
   
    # ---------------

    def __init__ (me, keyfunc) :

        me.keyfunc = keyfunc         # extract unique key (domain) from each item
        me.outques = {}              # outgoing queues sorted by domain
        me.paused  = {}              # paused queue keys with expiration time

        me.lock    = threading.RLock ()   # synchronize ops
        me.gotime  = threading.Event ()   # signal when items ready
        me.notime  = threading.Event ()   # signal when backoff period active

        # spawn new thread to watch queues for ready items
        watcher = threading.Thread (target = me._watcher , daemon = true)
        watcher.start ()
        
    # ---------------
    
    def _watcher (me) :
        'watch for queues to unpause after backoff'

        DEBUG and log (f'watcher started (me)')

        while true :

            try :
                # wait for a backoff period to be in effect
                me.notime.wait ()
                DEBUG and log (f'watcher : wakeup, backoff in effect')

                # get time here so it doesnt change after unpause checks, which skews results
                now = time.time ()

                with me.lock :

                    # --- check if any pauses expired
                    # slightly more efficient to copy unpause code here

                    for key in list (me.paused) :
                        me.unpause (key)

                    # --- get next wakeup time

                    nextcheck = 0
                    if len (me.paused) :
                        nextcheck = min (me.paused.values ())

                    # clear flag inside lock so we dont clear pauses added by intervening put ()
                    else :
                        # all done, no backoffs in effect
                        me.notime.clear ()

                # IMPORTANT - release lock before sleep !

                if nextcheck :
                    delta = max (nextcheck - now, 0)  # ensure not negative

                    # SET MAX SLEEP TIME HERE
                    # if not, short backoff (30s) could start and end before long backoff ends
                    # watcher would never wakeup to clear short backoff
                    # for safety, sleep minimum backoff time = least wasted time
                    # sleep longer if some wasted time is tolerable

                    delta = min (delta, 10)

                    DEBUG and log (f'watcher : sleep til next check : { delta:0.2f}')
                    time.sleep (delta)

                # restart loop and wait for another backoff period

            except Exception as e :
                log (f'EXCEPTION : { u.fmtexc (e) }')

    # ---------------

    def get (me) :
        'get item from queue.  blocks until ready.'
        # add block param if compatibility with queue.Queue desired

        DEBUG and log (f'trying get...')

        # --- keep looping til we get an item

        while true :

            me.gotime.wait ()

            DEBUG and log (f'get : its gotime!')

            # --- try to get an item
            # attempt may fail as other threads empty queue before we reach here

            with me.lock :

                active = [ x for x in me.outques if x not in me.paused ]   # names of active queues

                # size should be reliable under lock
                ready = [ a for a in active if len (me.outques [a]) ]

                if ready :
                    DEBUG and log (f'get : found ready queues : { ready }')
                    random.shuffle (ready)

                    for key in ready :
                        try :
                            item = me.outques [key].popleft ()
                            return item

                        except IndexError :
                            # for safety - not sure how to get here with lock?
                            log (f'deque pop failed ? { key = } : { len (me.outques [key] }')
                            pass

                DEBUG and log (f'get : nothing ready!  making gotime false')
                me.gotime.clear ()

            DEBUG and log (f'get : missed our shot, back to wait')

    # ---------------

    def putfront (me, item) :
        'return item to front of que to be next taken'

        key = me.keyfunc (item)

        with me.lock :
            que = me.outques.setdefault (key, deque ())
            que.appendleft (item)
            me.gotime.set ()

        size = len (que)
        DEBUG and log (f'put front in queue { key } : { item } : { size = }')

    # ---------------

    def put (me, item) :
        'return item to back of que'

        key = me.keyfunc (item)

        with me.lock :
            que = me.outques.setdefault (key, deque ())   
            que.append (item)   
            me.gotime.set ()

        size = len (que)
        DEBUG and log (f'put in queue { key } : { item } : { size = }')

    # ---------------

    def ispaused (me, item) :
        key = me.keyfunc (item)
        with me.lock :
            return key in me.paused

    # ---------------

    def pause (me, item, sec) :
        key = me.keyfunc (item)
        with me.lock :
            me.paused [key] = time.time () + sec
            me.notime.set ()

        DEBUG and log (f'pausing { key } for { sec } sec')

    # ---------------

    def unpause (me, key, force = false) :
        'check if key que is ready to unpause and do it'

        now = time.time ()

        with me.lock :
            expire = me.paused.get (key, 0)
            if expire <= now or force :
                me.paused.pop (key, 0)
                me.gotime.set ()   # signal items ready
                DEBUG and log (f'pausewatch : unpausing { key }')

    # ---------------

    def __len__ (me) :
        with me.lock :
            return sum ( len (x) for x in me.outques.values () )

    # ---------------

    def qsize (me) :  return len (me)  # for compatibility with queue.Queue

# end Pauseque }

# --- helpers
DEBUG = false

def log (msg) :
    tid   = threading.get_ident () % 10000
    stamp = f'{ time.time () % 1000:8.3f}'
    print (f'{ tid:4d} at { stamp } : { msg }', flush = true)

Usage
Pauseque acts like a typical thread-safe que.  Multiple threads can put() and get () objects.
Pauseque has an additional function, pause().  This is triggered by consumer threads when they want to pause a particular group of items (by domain in my case).  The que will stop returning those items during the pause period, and resume returning them when pause period ends.  Pauses are triggered by an external rate limiting algorithm in consumer threads (see notes for why).
unpause() method is mostly internal for watcher thread.  However consumer threads may want to use in case of dynamic rate limiting that shortens a backoff period.
Convenience functions ispaused() checks whether que is paused for any item, and putfront() puts an item back at front of que (next to be taken).  This is useful for multiple consumer threads checking rate limits: one consumer triggers a rate limit, other consumers check ispaused () right before downloading and put item back if domain is currently paused.
In terms of code from original post :
def dl_worker (que) :
    while true :
        item = que.get ()

        delay = rate_limit (item)   # check if this item triggers rate limit
        if delay :
            que.pause (item, delay)
            continue

        # do some prep on item..., then -

        if que.paused (item.domain) :   # check if another thread triggered rate limit
            que.putfront (item)
            continue

        # dl item...

# start pool of dl threads
dlque = Pauseque (get_domain)
workers = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool (5)
with workers :
    for x in workers._pool :
        workers.apply_async (dl_worker, dlque)

Advantages
Pauseque is much more efficient than original version.  Consumer threads never sleep, all waiting is handled by queue.  Pauseque uses threading.Event gotime to signal when items are available, so get() calls block until signaled.
Pauseque uses separate watcher thread to monitor groups for pause expiration and make them available again.  This check blocks on Event notime, which is set when a pause is initiated and cleared when all groups are active again.
Watcher thread has the only sleep() call in this code, to wakeup and check next group unpause time.  Much more efficient than previous code because it's only one thread and it sleeps for long periods (10+ seconds), vs every consumer thread sleeping multiple times per second.
Performance
Pauseque performs very well.  When unpause happens, consumer threads are processing items again within 1-2ms of scheduled resume time.
Put and get operations are quite fast.  5.5us per cycle for que.put (item) ; item = que.get () in single thread.
Notes
keyfunc is any way to sort queue items into groups for pausing.  In my case, download items are sorted by domain.  Can be used with other sorting methods for basis of pauses (eg sort by username for traffic shaping by sender).
Pauseque uses deque internally instead of queue to hold each group.  I used queues at first, but put-back items can only go at end of queue.  Want to preserve group ordering, and dequeue allows adding to either end.  As a bonus, my tests show that a put () - get () cycle is 3x faster with deque: 5.5us with deque vs 15.9us with queue.Queue.  Per:
python -m timeit -s 'import pauseque ; pq = pauseque.Pauseque (lambda x : str (x)) ; item = {"foo":"bar"}' -s 'pq.put (item) ; pq.get ()'
Rate limiting is done externally to Pauseque because it's a dynamic decision only consumer thread can make.  If a dl item is empty or already complete (duplicate request), then no dl is attempted and rate limit isn't triggered.  Likewise, if server response http code indicates a timeout or temporary failure, then pause is triggered regardless of static rate limit.  Pauseque can't evaluate these conditions, better to let consumer threads trigger a pause.
One missing feature is Pauseque doesn't preserve ordering between different groups.  It would be complex so I skipped it.
As a result, get() has to choose an item from all available (unpaused) groups.  If get() simply iterated over ready group list, then groups inserted in Pauseque first would be preferentially selected.  To prevent this, I use random.shuffle on ready before iterating in get().  This ensures every que has equal chance of being selected.  Not perfect soluton but good enough.
If you wanted to be more fair, perhaps you could weight the shuffle by number of items in group.  So longer groups have proportionally higher chance of being chosen.
I also fixed the egregious python devs' mistake of not implementing __len__ for queues.  Because why?  They're afraid it won't be accurate so they give us qsize instead?  Ridiculous.  Of course len is never reliable in multithreaded world.  Neither is list or dict or anything else.  That's a terrible reason to break the way every other container works.  Thanks for nothing, devs. :eyeroll:

Pipes
Found another potential solution.  Instead of queue, I could use a unix pipe (named or anonymous) for download items.  Then use select on pipe file descriptors to poll for inputs without time.sleep.  See example here.
Approach
One way this could work: Replace domain queues in Solution 1 (original post) with one pipe per domain.  Worker threads can use select on active pipes to check for download items not in backoff period.  With thread locks on pipe read after wakeup.
New Issue
This eliminates need for sleep polling in worker threads - mostly.  As long as incoming items are from previously seen domains, select polling works fine.  HOWEVER it breaks when item from new domain comes in:

worker threads wait for new items in pipes A,B,C with select
item arrives for new domain, causing creation of new pipe D
workers don't see item waiting on pipe D until new item in A,B,C wakes up select

Timeouts
That problem can be solved with periodic timeouts on select to check for new pipes.  Worker threads need to wake up periodically anyway - when backoff period expires to change the set of active pipes being watched.  Should be more efficient than sleep-polling as above.
Analysis
It's a good option.  Not sure it's my favorite though.  Pipes are more complex, and still needs periodic wakeups with nothing to do.  Put this in maybe pile for now.

Just goes to show: those unfamiliar with unix are doomed to recreate it badly :)

Why the effort ? Asyncio is a cross-platform wrapper around select and the other answer just explains how the already existing threadpool works , you are trying too much to reinvent already existing things.

@AhmedAEK asyncio is a royal pain : red/blue function nonsense, event loop blocking, unbounded coroutines (per your formulation).  It's a poor imitation of parallel processes / threads with serious drawbacks.  Why does asyncio.to_thread() exist?  Because asyncio alone doesn't cut it.

@AhmedAEK a threadpool submits jobs to threads.  it does not make decisions about : this item can proceed, this item needs to wait, do I take next item from incoming jobs or unpause waiting jobs?  jobs arrive in batches.  if main thread just shoves items into threadpool as they arrive, then many jobs for domain are submitted to threadpool before backoff is triggered.  Eg 100 jobs arrive at once, put them all in threadpool, job 20 triggers a backoff, oops now 80 jobs in threadpool need recycled by worker thread.
